# How to populate multiple items on a different page using a search bar?

Tags: php, html, database, searchbar

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help. I have just developed a search bar for my site which will be on every page loaded using an include function so they will all be the same. The code can read my database perfectly but I am at a lose on how to send more than one result to another page in the format that I need. The problem is that I post 2 to 3 variables to the next page in the url for each link of this sort and if the search bar returns more than 1 result then each result will need 2 to 3 variables to populate the next page.

Link example

```
<a href="page.php?gen=var1&media=var2&order=date_added DESC">Movies Home</a>
```

Here is the search bar code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search_term'])){ 
    $search_term = $_POST['search_term'];
    if (!empty($search_term)) {
            $query = "SELECT title FROM database WHERE title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_term)."%'";
            $query_run = mysql_query($query);
            $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
            $result = mysql_query($query_num_rows);

        if ($query_num_rows >= 1) {
            echo $query_num_rows.' results found:<br>';
            while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
                echo $query_row ['title']. '<br>';
            }
        }
        else{
            echo 'No results found.';
        }
}
  }
?>
```

This code currently echos on the current page. I am hopeing to pass it to a results page and populate multiple items depending on how many results were found in the search bar. Here is an example of the code that I would be hopeing to populate from the search bar on the target page.

```
<?php    
if (isset($var1)){
            $subject_set = mysql_query("Select * FROM database WHERE genre like '%".$info."%' and media = '".$med."' ORDER BY ".$sort." ", $connection);}           
        else{
            $subject_set = mysql_query("Select * FROM media", $connection);         
        }
        if (!$subject_set){
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
        }
       htlm code</div>

<?php } ?>
```

I was thinking that if I was even able to pass the results id's using an array and then retrieve the corrosponding results from the database on the target page.

Sorry I am still quite a novice at this type of coding and I hope I did not confuse anyone with what I am trying to say. Thank you for your time and hopefully I can get this problem sorted. Thanks again.

Comment: use session variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the results on other pages, consider putting them in SESSION variables.

```
<?php 
session_start ( ); // at top of page
...


$theIndex=0;
while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    echo $query_row ['title']. '<br>';
    $_SESSION['searchResult'][$theIndex]  =$query_row ['title'];
    $theIndex++;
```

}

Then on your the page where you want to display the results, loop through the SESSION['searchResult'] and echo it out...

```
<?php 
session_start ( ); // at top of page

$theResults = $_SESSION['searchResult'];

foreach ($theResults as $key=>$value){
echo htmlentities($value) . "<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sessions seems to be the way unfortunately I have not used them before. Just a couple of questions about the code. Where did you get the variables $key=>$value from? Also at the top of the page do I only put <?php session_start (); ?> and then do I have to stop the session afterwards? Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Sessions are not all that difficult. Dive in!